# iOS Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 before ask for location permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm getting

```
Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1
```

error in `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`(which means user didn't allow to use location services) before app asks for location permission.
Is there a way to prevent that error or at least to check if location permission has been asked already?

Comment: user can change permission later via settings even if he/she allowed it before. better to check it every time you need to access the location.

Comment: can you give a source for this error meaning that they didn't grant permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean CLAuthorizationStatus? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clauthorizationstatus

```
let status: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus
if status == .notDetermined {
// Ask permissions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can watch changes in authorizations by defining

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:  
            // do what is needed if you have access to location
        case .denied, .restricted:
            // do what is needed if you have no access to location
        case .notDetermined:
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        @unknown default:
            // raise an error - This case should never be called
        }
}
```

so you do not have to explicitly check the status each time you ask for a position.